# How to setup external SMTP emailing on a local Magento?

Tags: magento-1, email, smtp

I am trying to test some email sending from my localhost. I'd like to use an external SMTP server for this matter. I am using Windows 7/XAMPP. I tried configuring sendmail.ini with no luck. Where/how can I tell Magento to use specific settings for sending emails?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the SMTP host and port in System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending Settings.

For sending emails from an external SMTP server, however, I would recommend the free extension [SMTP Pro](https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension).

Ashley (the extension creator) [describes](http://www.aschroder.com/projects/) what the advantages are:

> This Magento extension is created for expert users who need full control of the Magento SMTP server settings. You can control authentication, security and specify your own host and port. The extension supports self-testing and Magento newsletters. This extension now also has the ability to easily configure and send from Gmail or Google Apps email addresses.

Comment: Am I to understand, that this is not possible out of the box in Magento?

Comment: You can set the host and port. I added the information. I also added a quote explaining why you may want to use the extension.

Comment: SMTP settings are just for Windows hosts.

Comment: I am using SMTP pro extension in localhost, testing mail working good, but order mail not sending in localhost, how to solve this error?

Comment: I have configured all smtp details but i am getting error command not implemented