# SMTP Extension Installation

Tags: email, smtp

I am newbie in magento, I am trying to get installed the aschroder SMTP extension recommended by [Mathias](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/16/matthias-zeis) in this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11438/how-to-setup-external-smtp-emailing-on-a-local-magento) from the project's page in [GitHub](https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension). I've checked [Ashley's blog](http://www.aschroder.com/2010/05/installing-a-magento-extension-manually-via-ftp-or-ssh/) for instructions but I am lost. Could you please share with me directions for this installation?

Thank you very much.

Comment: We're just as lost — what part don't you understand?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't feel equipped to install it manually, you could always install it using Magento Connect.

1. [A Wiki on how to Use Magento Connect Manager](https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/how_tu_use_magento_connect_manager_-_downloader)
2. [ASchroder.com SMTP Pro Email - Free and Easy Magento Emailing for SMTP, Gmail or Google Apps email](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aschroder-com-smtp-pro-email-free-and-easy-magento-emailing-for-smtp-gmail-or-google-apps-email.html)

They also offer a complete guide on how to install this over here:

[Home/Magento/Installing a Magento Extension manually via FTP or SSH](http://www.aschroder.com/2010/05/installing-a-magento-extension-manually-via-ftp-or-ssh/)

You should manage to come right if you follow the step-by-step instructions, it really isn't too complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @moose, I had previously checked option 2 but it only supports v1.5. Currently I have 1.7. I've also previously installed extensions using connect manager. Reading the complete guide is where I don't know specifically what folders from the project put into my current installation folders. Thanks again.