# Transaction Emails Magento 1.9.0.1 AWS and Amazon SES

Tags: magento-1.9, email, amazon-web-services, smtp, aws

I am working on a magento store which is installed on AWS EC2. I have setup Amazon SES to handle email and I installed the extension aschroder SMTP which supports Amazon SES. Using this system I am able to successfully send out the test email using the SMTP extension connected to my SES account. When I place a test order I am able to add a comment which immediately sends the comment email out to the customer. But the customer never receives the order emails. Even if I manually click the Send Email button on the order it never arrives.

I have searched the internet for days looking for solutions. I have made sure my SES account is no longer in sandbox mode, checked to ensure all of my cron tasks are working correctly. This has me stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked Magento's Mail Sending settings in the Admin?

Comment: I just found another SE question about it: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11438/how-to-setup-external-smtp-emailing-on-a-local-magento

Comment: I have checked the sending settings. I am using an ubuntu server. Also like I said, some emails send just fine while others don't

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. It seems to be a bug in some versions of magento. The solution is found here and requires you to alter the source file for the Order.php file and remove a line that causes the email routine to return without sending the mail.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/m/viewthread/1025895/#t483183

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can check your mail log?

```
Jan 29 22:27:30 admin.node postfix/smtp[4581]: 5328340775: to=<api@xxxxx.co.uk>, relay=email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com[54.171.25.162]:587, 
delay=0.55, delays=0.02/0/0.15/0.38, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok 0000014x235c7ce3fc3-07fewrg1b-x40a-4542-aafc-d9g34gg4ec4b-000000)
```

probably they get into spam or just rejected

Notifications

> To help you track your email sending, Amazon SES has a
>   built-in mechanism to forward you bounce, complaint, and delivery
>   notifications. Amazon SES can send the bounce and complaint messages
>   to you in one of two ways: by email or through Amazon Simple
>   Notification Service (Amazon SNS). Delivery notifications are
>   available only through Amazon SNS.

also check your SES statistics

Comment: Ok so I have switched on email logging with the SMTP extension. I now see that the transactional emails don't appear to get into the extension as they never show in either of the logs for aschroder. Any idea why that would be?