# Magento 2: Order conformation mail is not sending?

Tags: magento2, email, purchase-order

In my project, when a user creates an account they get the mail. But after making an order neither the customer nor the admin gets the mail. I found many solutions but that's all for Magento 1.9 or below. I am using Magento 2. I need a solution with or without using **cron** job. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you checked Configure -> Sales Emails enable or not?

Comment: yes i checked it.

Comment: Is this issues you are facing on local machine or on server?

Comment: on local machine

Comment: which version are you using? Magento 2.x.x?

Comment: magento version 2

Comment: have you seen your placed order in admin panel?

Comment: yes. admin can view orders. and he can send emails .but i need to get mails to admin & customers when they place order.

Comment: have you done with reindex and recompile? if not then do once.

Comment: ok. i will check it.

Comment: my cron jobs are running for every 1 minute. and i encountered that i don;t have "cron_email_queue","cron_email_recepients" tables.

Comment: Chirag,  if my cron jobs are running correctly then do i need to reindex it?

Comment: please check my solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/212031/49821

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Cron then just disable Email Async Setting from Admin.

**Admin -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails -> General Settings -> Asynchronous sending -> Disable**.

It should work for you If your server is configured for sending Email.

Answer (score 0):

In sales emails configuration enable the order email sending and email templates as shown below image.

[image]

Comment: i already made these changes.

Answer (score 0):

You might not able to send any email from local, because you have not configure SMTP on local server (Wamp/Xampp).
You can used below free extension & input your gmail smtp details.

https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp

This will resolve your problem.

Comment: but what if i'm using it on server? . Actually i don't want to use extensions. is there is other solutions without using extensions?

Comment: you can remove this extension on server, Magento will auto send emails if your server has email server configure.

Comment: but in server also i face this issue:(

Comment: You can check this question for configuration smtp  on local http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11438/how-to-setup-external-smtp-emailing-on-a-local-magento

Comment: it also about using extensions. when i run it on the server also it doesn't send mail.

Comment: any error showing?

Comment: no errors.but mails are not sending.

Comment: Yes, you are using gmail emailid for testing, so you need to allowing less security to account. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en  . This extension is only for testing proposed, can't be used as long time solution.

Comment: This might be one of solution you can used, http://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-send-mail-using-your-smtp-detail/

Comment: Dev, i think it can't help me. my cron jobs are working per 1minute. but emails are not being send.

Comment: Dev, in my db "cron_email_queue","cron_email_recepients" tables are missing. is it a problem?